# Apply Style to every element of type X in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm currently trying to find a way to style all controls in a UWP app with the same Style/type. To be specific I want to set `OpticalMarginAlignment` to `TrimSideBearings` for every - I mean every `TextBlock`.

I know I can create a Style in App.xaml without `x:Key` property like this:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
</Style>
```

But this does not change the style of TextBlocks which are in a DataTemplate (which according to similar questions is *by design*). However I don't want to have to set a Style for each TextBlock used in a DataTemplate, so I thought about other solutions:

1. Create a `StyledTextBlock` element derived from `TextBlock` (not working cause `TextBlock` is sealed)
2. Create a `StyledDataTemplate` element derived from `DataTemplate` (not working cause I haven't found anything in DataTemplate I could hook into to load the Style and because there is no `DataTemplate.Resources`)
3. Create a `StyledTextBlock` element derived from `UserControl` with a `TextBlock` element inside

Number 3 is even working, though it would require me to create a DependencyProperty for every `TextBlock.DependencyProperty` I want to use to style the `StyledTextBlock` like this:

```xml
<StyledTextBlock Text="Example" FontSize="10" />
```

To keep code amount low I could create a TextStyle DependencyProperty in `StyledTextBlock` and set it like this, but I don't like this solution as well:

```xml
<StyledTextBlock Text="Example">
    <StyledTextBlock.TextStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
        </Style>
     </StyledTextBlock.Style>
</StyledTextBlock>
```

Does anyone have another idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Using the Usercontrol and dependency property were on the right direction. I’m afraid there’re no other ways to get it :)

Comment: I guess you stuck with your third solution?